# RxJava replacement for AsyncTaskLoader+ContentProvider

Tags: android, listview, android-contentprovider, rx-java, asynctaskloader

Does anyone know if it is possible to use RxJava to monitor a SQLite database table for changes and update the UI (a ListView) on detecting any updates. i.e. basically a replacement for the functionality of AsyncTaskLoader and a ContentProvider?

A working example / links to a working sample would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio

Comment: or https://github.com/square/sqlbrite

Comment: It's certainly possible, but why would you want to replace it?